# Using MS Ajax Minfier 4.0 for Asp.Net MVC 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-mvc, performance, asp.net-mvc-2

I am planning to use **MS Ajax Minifier** with **Asp.Net MVC 2.0** for handling the Js and Css files. Does anyone has experience with MS Ajax Minifier? I have following questions regarding this.

1. Is it the best way to use JS/CSS files in Asp.Net MVC or is there a better way. E.g. **YUI Compressor, Telerik Extension for MVC**?
2. As I understand we can use this to convert **SomeFile.js** to **SomeFile.min.js** at the build time. However In my mvc Views I still have the Script reference pointing to **SomeFile.js**. How does the browser will pick the **SomeFile.min.js** file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's one possibility to use. The integration when building is a nice asset and it has hypercrunching.
2. You must use the `SomeFile.min.js` in your script reference. But in Visual Studio you can have an uncompressed file with this name `SomeFile-vsdoc.js` for intellisense coding (in which you can also use xml comments which will be picked up by VS.

Another approach would be to use [SquishIt](http://www.codethinked.com/post/2010/05/26/SquishIt-The-Friendly-ASPNET-JavaScript-and-CSS-Squisher.aspx).

Grz, Kris.

Comment: Thanks. I used Squishit as suggested and its really simple to use and brilliant.